# How to change background-image for only next h2

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, background-image

jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nag").click(function(){
        $(".nag").not(this).next(".zaw").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).next(".zaw").slideToggle("slow");
        $("h2").css("background-image", "url(img/arr_top.png)");    
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="nag">
       <h2>H2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="zaw">
     </div>
<div class="nag">
       <h2>H2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="zaw">
     </div> 
<div class="nag">
       <h2>H2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="zaw">
     </div>
```

Hi, this is my code to slide up div after click one of div's. After second click slideToggle.

What should i add to jquery to change background-image for only next h2 (now all h2 changed after click) after click and after second click background-image goes back to first value of background-image (img/arr.png)

I would be very grateful for your help, because the matter seems simple and I have two days add .next () in different places for nothing :)

Comment: Where is your next `H2`? I think you are looking for `$(this).find("h2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're getting global selector i.e. h2 and not using h2 inside clicked element.

Replace this:

```
$("h2").css("background-image", "url(img/arr_top.png)");
```

With this:

```
$(this).find("h2").css("background-image", "url(img/arr_top.png)");
```

Answer (score 0):

`h2` comes under the div so it should be or it will effect globally

```
$(this).children("h2")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nag").click(function() {
    $(".nag").not(this).next(".zaw").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).next(".zaw").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).children("h2").toggleClass('bg')
  });
});
```

```css
.nag {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.bg {
  background-image: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nag">
  <h2>H2</h2>
</div>
<div class="zaw"></div>
```

Comment: My 2 days = Your 5 min - Thanks! How about goes back to first value after second click ? Is this difficult ?

Comment: instead add a class with background image and toggle it like i have done in the snippet @Michal